# Curve Shape List Item

Tags: android, listview

Hey i am new in android...

Actually, i don't know that how to develop curve style ListView...  please give me concept/code to develop curve shape list item...

I want to develop [these kind of scrolling menu(Visit this link)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.u360mobile.scranton&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLnUzNjBtb2JpbGUuc2NyYW50b24iXQ..) which is display in second number screen-shot on play store...

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

Just create a shape.xml in your drawable folder and put this code inside

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#313131"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:top="10dp"
    android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
```

Then you can set it as background in your list item. Just "play" with the stroke, radius dimensions and the colors in the shape to create your own custom one.

**Instructions:**

Go file-->New-> Android XML file and create a shape xml file.

Copy-Paste above code

Then go to your list item xml file and set    android:background="@drawable/shape"
where shape is the shape.xml file you created above and is located in the drawable folder.

In case that you want to add  the list item programmatically you have to do something like
this `listItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);` or something similar.
Hope that helps.